# Mouse clicks won't work (Linux Mint KDE)

Tags: linux-mint, kde, chrome

I'm using linux mint 15 with KDE and today I realized my mouse clicks on Google Chrome often don't work and it only throws out the messages:

```
(google-chrome:2971): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
[2971:2971:1216/170258:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(228)] Gdk:IA__gdk_window_get_events: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
```

I don't know what triggered this error but I can see these logs when starting the browser through the terminal and when I'm trying to click it. I already reset my KDE Settings, but that wasn't the problem.

EDIT:
I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 to work again with the computer but it seems the same problem occurs... I can start a program and afterwards I can't click anywhere. The programs I have installed are only a few:
Chrome
Fbmessenger
Skype
PyCharm
Django
Mysql-Workbench
FileZilla

Could this be caused by some kind of malware? I only installed Ubuntu on my second partition.

Comment: Is this Chrome from Mint? What version?

Comment: It's Version 31.0.1650.63 and I think it's for Ubuntu but i'm not sure... I installed it like half a year ago. But somehow different other applications don't work aswell. I really believe it's a KDE Problem since sometimes i can't even click my console/aptana or even my desktop.